# [R/emmeans]: select specific contrast in emmeans

Tags: r, regression, mixed-model, linear-model

I created `lmm` using `lmer`.
I want then look at the contrast using `emmeans` (just an overview below)

```
$contrasts
 contrast                  estimate   SE  df lower.CL upper.CL t.ratio p.value
 A - B    14.3927 1.40 102     9.91    18.87  10.310 <.0001 
 A - C    -0.9537 1.45 154    -5.55     3.64  -0.659 0.5957 
 A - D    14.2376 1.45 154     9.64    18.84   9.845 <.0001 
 A - E    11.2341 1.51 155     6.42    16.05   7.420 <.0001 
 A - F    12.9106 1.60 154     7.84    17.98   8.089 <.0001 
 A - H    12.5250 1.45 154     7.93    17.12   8.661 <.0001 
 A - I    14.2004 1.45 154     9.60    18.80   9.819 <.0001 
 B - L    -15.3463 1.45 154   -19.94   -10.75 -10.612 <.0001 
 B - J    -0.1550 1.45 154    -4.75     4.44  -0.107 0.9487 
 B - K    -3.1586 1.51 155    -7.97     1.65  -2.086 0.0832
```

However, I only want to look at specific contrasts for example `A - B` and `D - E`

I know I can use the

`emmeans(l_glm_l1_cage[[1]], pairwise ~ timegroups, adjust = "fdr", at=list(timegroups=c("A", "B", "D", "E")))`

but this of course gives me the pairwise comparisons.
Any suggestions?

Comment: try reading `? contrast` and `vignette("contrasts", "emmeans")` for starters. Note that in the `method` argument, you may specify a list of contrast coefficients.

Comment: I recommend using a one-sided formula and calling `contrast` on the result.

Comment: Thank you. I think I kind of got the solution. First I define the interested factors e.g. `A=c(0,0,0,0,1,0)` and `B=c(0,1,0,0,0,0,0)`. Then I call `contrast(emm1, method = list("A-B" = A - B))`. This seemed to work

Comment: I'd have thought that it should be `A = c(1,0,0,0,0,0)` but what you have is cirrect if A is the next-to-last level

Comment: Yes, you are right, what I wrote does not match the data! Sorry about that